# org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I have a code base which is deployed in a server where **I don't have any access other than uploading war file**. I have tested the application using apache tomcat 7 locally and it works perfectly.



I have a code in JAVA which triggers a remote web browser instance, it works perfectly when deployed locally but when I uploaded the war file to a server I get an exception as shown in the image below.

```
nodeIP = "10.52.239.111";
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), capability);
```

Server in which the war has been deployed has an Ip address of "172.32.xxx.xxx"

I get an exception of **org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException** I googled it and found some threads on where it is pointing and asking to change host files address and all. But I didn't understand how can I fix in my situation as Server configuration can't be controlled by me at all.

```
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setBrowserName("firefox");
    FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
    fp.setPreference("browser.private.browsing.autostart", true);
    //fp.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.ALLOWED_HOSTS_PREFERENCE, "localhost,localhost.localdomain");
    String Node = "http://" + nodeIP + ":5556/wd/hub";
    try {
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), capability);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help highly appreciated.
[image: Exception Screenshot]

Comment: This looks more of conflict in jar being used, are you using any selenium jars or appium or any other package ?? can you post the exception screenshot .

Comment: @Pankaj I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar, selenium-java-2.47.1.jar and I am no where referring or using Appium in my project.

Exception Screenshot is posted above. I don't have access to screenshot as this is deployed in Server. The best I could is debug until where it is throwing an Exception and taken a screenshot as shown in above image.